# Angular Material Table won't display Observable<{ [key: string]: number; }>

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, angular-material

My REST API returns a `Observable<{ [key: string]: number; }>`. 
It's a JAX-RS web service returning a `Map<String, Integer>` and annotated with `@ApiOperation(value = "Lorem ipsum", response = Integer.class, responseContainer = "Map")` from Swagger, which generates my Angular client.

My `mat-table` definition looks like this:

### HTML:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="myDataSource">
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>

    <mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: columnsToDisplay"></mat-row>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let property">{{property.name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Value</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let property">{{property.value}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

### Component:

```
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {

    columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'value'];

    myDataSource: Observable<{ [key: string]: number; }>;

    constructor(private webClient: WebClientService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myDataSource = this.webClient.getData();
    }

}
```

Angular doesn't display anything and doesn't output warnings with this code. In my browsers network request monitor, I can see data like `{ "thing1": 1, "thing2": 2 }` arriving at the client. A simple `this.myDataSource.subscribe(x => console.log(x))` shows the same data in the browser's console. What can I do to display this data in a Table?

**Edit:** To clearify things, here is more code:

HTTP GET method:

```
public getData(observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<{ [key: string]: number; }>;
public getData(observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<{ [key: string]: number; }>>;
public getData(observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<{ [key: string]: number; }>>;
public getData(observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {

    let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

    // to determine the Accept header
    let httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
    ];
    let httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
    if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected != undefined) {
        headers = headers.set("Accept", httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
    }

    // to determine the Content-Type header
    let consumes: string[] = [
    ];

    return this.httpClient.get<{ [key: string]: number; }>(`${this.basePath}/lorem/ipsum`,
        {
            withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
            headers: headers,
            observe: observe,
            reportProgress: reportProgress
        }
    );
}
```

Data is received in the above noted form, but won't show up in the `mat-table`. Changing `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit` produces the error `Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'dataSource: undefined'. Current value: 'dataSource: [object Object]'."`.
Assigning the received data directly via subscribe() produces the error `Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource`.

Comment: What's the problem? What are you currently seeing? What is `webClient.getData()`? What does that return? You will need to provide us with more information. There is not enough for us to get a clear picture of the problem. Whatever you think would help, add it to your post.

Comment: I made an edit to the post.

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to pass an `Observable` to the `[dataSource]`?

Comment: The error message states I could pass an Observable. Unfortunately it says nothing about the observable content.

Comment: Im just looking at [the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#observable-stream-of-data-arrays) and I think that the data needs to be an array. It can be an array or a Observable that emits an array. You are trying to give it an object. You need to map to an array.

Comment: Think about the type of data a table would display. With an array, each element of the array would be a row. So each item should be an object. The properties on that object will be the columns. So your data should be an array of objects. You only have one object. Maybe just wrap it in an array. Use `getData().map(data => [data])`

Comment: So what happened? Do you have an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit.  You need the table to render before adding the data.

Comment: Now I get an error in the browser console: `Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'dataSource: undefined'. Current value: 'dataSource: [object Object]'."`

Comment: Otherwise, when I leave out the type declaration for myDataSource and assign the value directly in the `subscribe()` method, I get an error "Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource"